Variable group not resolved in File Creator task in Azure Pipelines
I have a project in Azure DevOps to build and release e2e tests for other FE projects. We are moving from conventional GUI pipelines with task groups to YAML pipelines, but I am having issues when using variables from a variable group.
What I had:

a Build pipeline to build and publish the artifact --> this works fine in yaml too
a Build pipeline with a few tasks - download artifact, npm install, File Creator task to create an .env file (variables were defined directly there in the GUI), npm command to run tests
and release.

What I have now:

YAML template for the file creation and test running (template as I will be using it instead of a task group for other projects, too)
YAML file for the build and release - it builds the artifact then includes the template.

The variables should be read from a variable group in the library where my project resides. The variable group has access to the pipeline. The pipeline validates, but then the run tests task fails as the variables are not resolved. Am I referencing them in the correct way? I would like to avoid hardcoding the variables in the yml file.
Here is my multistage yml pipeline
variables:
- group: End2EndV3
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/main
stages:
- stage: BuildArtifact
  jobs:
  - job: Job_1
    displayName: Agent job 1
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-2019
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 1
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: Use Node 10.x
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 10.x
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      inputs:
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: MyArtifact'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: MyArtifact
- stage: RunTests
  jobs:
  - job: RunTests
    steps:
    - template: template-test-release.yml
    
...

and here the yml template causing issues
steps:
- task: eliostruyf.build-task.custom-build-task.file-creator@6
  displayName: 'Create cypress.env.json'
  inputs:
    filepath: 'somefilepath/MyArtifact/cypress.env.json'
    filecontent: |
     {
       "myVariable": "$(myVariableFromLibraryValue)",
     }
    fileoverwrite: true
    verbose: true

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm ci install'
  inputs:
    command: ci
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact'
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run tests'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run cy:run:tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results *-test-output.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '*-test-output.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact/cypress/results'
    mergeTestResults: true



To pass a variable from a variable group to the template, it's suggested to pass via parameters as suggested by Rui below. However, testing your scripts, the cypress.env.json file was successfully create on my side.  Would you please let me know why you believe "the run tests task fails as the variables are not resolved"? What's the value of myVariable in the log of eliostruyf.build-task.custom-build-task.file-creator@6 task?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Thanks for suggesting to review the logs! I had missed them completely. I kept looking at the failing test task logs, but did not see the expanded variables in the create file log. So indeed that part works.
My build is still failing, but the issue must lie elsewhere between env creation and npm command. FYI, the reason I thought the variables were not expanded was that my Cypress tests fail at the first step, i.e. a cy.request() that cannot find a correct url (which I provide in the env).

According to your description, I am guessing your test steps need the artifact published by BuildArtifact stage. But in your RunTests stage, you didn't download it, so your test can't find it in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact. You need to download your artifact "MyArtifact" to your test working directory. I share a sample below. If it doesn't work for you, create a new question with the detailed info, including error message.

Try passing the variable from the variable group as a parameter to the template where these will be used.
For example:
Main pipeline
variables:
- group: End2EndV3

# code omitted for brevity

- stage: RunTests
  jobs:
  - job: RunTests
    steps:
    - template: template-test-release.yml
      parameters:
        foo: "$(myVariableFromLibraryValue)" # from variable group

template-test-release.yml:
parameters:
  - name: foo
    type: string
    displayName: 'Foo'

steps:
- task: eliostruyf.build-task.custom-build-task.file-creator@6
  displayName: 'Create cypress.env.json'
  inputs:
    filepath: 'somefilepath/MyArtifact/cypress.env.json'
    filecontent: |
     {
       "myVariable": "${{ parameters.foo }}",
     }
    fileoverwrite: true
    verbose: true
    
# .....


Recommended reading:

Azure Pipelines - understand variable syntax


Thank you, I followed the suggestion and used parameters, but the error persists. I am wondering if the variables are written to the wrong file for example, but I cannot seem to figure what is happening.

@Bice double-check the casing of the variable names i.e. are you using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters? Are you using special characters?

Indeed it was a tipo issue, a couple $ missing that were apparent when I checked the logs. Thank you for your help! I stil have not achieved a successful build, but the error is somewhere else as now all variables are expanded.

Add a DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task in your template-test-release.yml before creating cypress.env.json file. Set the downloadPath to the working directory of your npm test.
steps:
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'MyArtifact'
    downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath' #The working directory of your npm test
- task: eliostruyf.build-task.custom-build-task.file-creator@6
  displayName: 'Create cypress.env.json'
  inputs:
    filepath: 'somefilepath/MyArtifact/cypress.env.json'
    filecontent: |
     {
       "myVariable": "$(myVariableFromLibraryValue)", 
     }
    fileoverwrite: true
    verbose: true
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      ls
      cat cypress.env.json
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact'

I don't know the value of somefilepath. Ensure, your artifact and cypress.env.json are in the working directory of your npm test. You can run ls to list all the files in the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/somefilepath/MyArtifact before "npm ci install".

All solved. In the end, and it took me a longer time it should have to figure it out, there were still missing quotation marks and an extra comma in the env file - since I had not copied the last version from my local repo but edited it directly on Azure, the errors did not pop up, and it being a template it missed the validation step.
Thank you again for the advice, I can mark it as fully resolved!
